# How to get the immediate child elements of the root element using C# and XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, .net-4.0

```
 <Document>
    <Heading1>
         <text>Heading Title</text>   
         <para>para1</para>
         <para>para2</para>
         <para>para3</para>
     </Heading1>
    <Heading1>
         <text>2nd Heading Title</text>   
         <para>para4</para>
         <para>para5</para>
         <para>para6</para>
         <Heading2>
              <text>3rd Heading Title</text>   
              <para>para4</para>
              <para>para5</para>
         </Heading2>       
     </Heading1>
 </Document>
```

This is XML Document. Now, i want to parse this XML file using C# (4.0). Here, I want to get all the Heading1 elements without using that element name in my program. For example, don't use `document.GetElementsByTagName("Heading1");`. How i get it. Guide me get out of this issue.

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using LINQ to XML, you can do:

```
var headings = yourXDocument.Root.Elements();
```

Using [Nodes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.nodes.aspx) instead of [Elements()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342765.aspx) will also return text nodes and comments, which is apparently not what you want.

Comment: Ah, `Elements()` would be more appropriate here.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the child elements of the document or element through the [`Elements()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342765.aspx) method if using LINQ to XML.

```
XDocument doc = ...;

var query = doc.Root.Elements();
```

Comment: wouldn't `doc.Elements()` return the document element (`<Document>` here) instead of its children (`<Heading1>` here) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `XmlDocument`, this works:

```
var elements = doc.SelectNodes("/*/*");
```

That finds all child elements of the top-level element irrespective of any of their names.  It's usually safer to specify the names if you know them, so that elements with unexpected names don't get returned in your list - use `/Document/Heading1` to do this.